# How to convert FileInfo into FileInfo[]

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, system.io.fileinfo

I have been working on a program that requires a different approach to finish a job using try and catch nested within another `try/catch`.

For this purpose I have had to create a set of files as strings and then converted them to `FileInfo`.

```
IEnumerable<string> paths = null;
foreach (String fil in paths)
    FileInfo h = new FileInfo(fil);
```

So That wasn't so difficult, I require `FileInfo` to be in the form of a `FileInfo[]` array to continue the program however.

```
System.IO.FileInfo[] files = null;
```

Simply put, what is the best method to convert one type to the other, either directly from the string of from the converted `FileInfo` into a `FileInfo` array (`FileInfo[]`)?

Comment: A `FileInfo[]` array is precisely: `FileInfo[][]`. i.e. not what you want.

Comment: Also. If `paths` is null, how will you create an array?

Comment: Paths is not null, that's just the setup line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not directly?

```
paths.Select(p => new FileInfo(p)).ToArray();
```

Comment: @Adsy2010: Note that you need at least .NET 3.5 for `using System.Linq`.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah or create a single-item array:

```
FileInfo[] files = new FileInfo[] { info };
```

Comment: The method I am using is a sub method requiring the addition to anything already in the array

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
var result = paths.Select(p => new FileInfo(p)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `Linq` select to create your `FileInfo[]`

```
 IEnumerable<string> paths = null; // assuming you are going to fill this with filenames
 FileInfo[] fileInfos = paths.Select(p => new FileInfo(p)).ToArray();
```